# Read from a file into an array and stop if a ":" is found in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I in Ruby read a string from a file into an array and only read and save in the array until I get a certain marker such as ":" and stop reading?

Any help would be much appreciated =)

For example:

```
10.199.198.10:111  test/testing/testing  (EST-08532522)
10.199.198.12:111  test/testing/testing  (EST-08532522)
10.199.198.13:111  test/testing/testing  (EST-08532522)
```

Should only read the following and be contained in the array:

```
10.199.198.10
10.199.198.12
10.199.198.13
```

Answer (score 13):

This is a rather trivial problem, using [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000803):

```
results = open('a.txt').map { |line| line.split(':')[0] }

p results
```

Output:

```
["10.199.198.10", "10.199.198.12", "10.199.198.13"]
```

`String#split` breaks a string at the specified delimiter and returns an array; so `line.split(':')[0]` takes the first element of that generated array.

In the event that there is a line without a `:` in it, `String#split` will return an array with a single element that is the whole line.  So if you need to do a little more error checking, you could write something like this:

```
results = []

open('a.txt').each do |line|
  results << line.split(':')[0] if line.include? ':'
end

p results
```

which will only add split lines to the results array if the line has a `:` character in it.